# Symfony is not generating bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I installed fresh Symfony (with "symfony new test") on a fresh LAMP system. I'm trying to generate a bundle but it fails. The output is:

```
tugrul@tugrul-mint ~/tmp/test2 $ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace NV/TestdBundle --bundle-name=NVTestdBundle --dir=/home/tugrul/tmp/test2/src --format yml --structure

Welcome to the Symfony2 bundle generator  
BLABLABLA
Do you confirm generation [yes]? 

 Bundle generation  

[Twig_Error_Syntax]                                                                                                                                                                      
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Level "info" is not defined, use one of: 100, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500, 550, 600") in "bundle/index.html.twig.twig".  

[Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException]                                               
Level "info" is not defined, use one of: 100, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500, 550, 600
```

PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2015 15:24:49)
```

On the production server with exact same version of PHP, Symfony are successfully create a bundle, but not on the local development box.

Am I missing something? Or is there anything to be installed first to run symfony that not mentioned on the documentation?

Regards.

Comment: check into your ./app/config/config_dev.yml. I think level "info" not defined for monolog

Comment: whats it i'm looking for? my local config has no difference with the one on the server. one is running fine and other isn't. and the really weird thing is i cant find my error on google. [link](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=%22Level+info+is+not+defined%22)

Comment: well, i had a dirty fix but its not a real solution. i added a new item to monolog level definitions array.
/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php, added **'info'=>'INFO',** line to $levels variable.

Comment: am pretty sure something else is ALSO wrong, causing this, seeing as how the error is displaying bundle/index.html.twig.twig <- notice the 2 times twig

Comment: there are some files with double twig extensions in the generator bundle.

`$ find |grep "twig\.twig"`

Comment: The double ".twig" extension is normal in this case because we use a Twig template to generate a Twig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the locale. Set it to en_US.UTF-8 and its ok now. Spent 2 days for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this error. The following commands work for me:

```
$ symfony new test
$ cd test/
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=NV/TestdBundle --bundle-name=NVTestdBundle --dir=src --format=yml --structure
```

Note that I've changed the `--dir` option value to `src` because I'm inside the project's directory.

If still doesn't work for you, remember that you can append `-vvv` to any Symfony command to output very detailed error information.